# boost::bind as l-value object

Tags: c++, functor, boost-bind, lvalue

Is there way to do something like this (MS VS 2008)?

```
boost::bind mybinder = boost::bind(/*something is binded here*/);
mybinder(/*parameters here*/); // <--- first call
mybinder(/*another parameters here*/); // <--- one more call
```

I tried

```
int foo(int){return 0;}

boost::bind<int(*)(int)> a = boost::bind(f, _1);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Accept some previous answers please. You've been here for over a year, which is more than enough time to learn how SO works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind returns unspecified type, so you can't directly create a variable of the type. There is however a type template `boost::function` that is constructible for any function or functor type. So:

```
boost::function<int(int)> a = boost::bind(f, _1);
```

should do the trick. Plus if you are not binding any values, only placeholders, you can do without the `bind` altogether, because `function` is constructible from function pointers too. So:

```
boost::function<int(int)> a = &f;
```

should work as long as `f` is `int f(int)`. The type made it to C++11 as `std::function` to be used with C++11 closures (and `bind`, which was also accepted):

```
std::function<int(int)> a = [](int i)->int { return f(i, 42); }
```

note, that for directly calling it in C++11, the new use of `auto` is easier:

```
auto a = [](int i)->int { return f(i, 42); }
```

but if you want to pass it around, `std::function` still comes in handy.

Comment: If you're using C++11 and lambdas, you should use `std::function`.

Comment: @Tomalak: I extended the C++11 part and switched to `std::` there.

Answer (score 3):

```
int foo(int){return 0;}
boost::function<int(int)> a = boost::bind(f, _1);
```

Comment: That's not right either. `a` should be fine to equate directly to `foo` as a function pointer- there's no need to bind here.

Comment: I got "error C2079: 'a' uses undefined class 'boost::function<Signature>'"

Comment: @fogbit: Then you did not `#include` boost.function.

Comment: @DeadMG: I know it's not required, but it's not "not right" either. I went for the solution that's closest to the original code. If you want to take it further, the OP could replace the entire call to `a` with the integer literal `0`.